# DAX expression equivalent to SQL "WHERE ColumnA='Yes' OR ColumnB='No' OR ColumnC='Yes' OR ColumnD='No'

Tags: dax

I'm trying to find the DAX expression that will produce the result from the SQL query below. Thank you
Select Count(ID) AS CNT

FROM myTale

WHERE
ColumnA='Yes' OR ColumnB='No' OR ColumnC='Yes' OR ColumnD='No'

Comment: DAX utilizes similar language constraints for measures. I'd suggest searching for `COUNT` or `DISTINCTCOUNT` functions, `FILTER` use, and how `CALCULATE` will treat your data. Do some careful reading on `FILTER` and `CALCULATE` and how both affect your data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try a pattern like this:

```
CALCULATE(COUNT(Column), FILTER(Table, Condition || Condition || Condition || Condition))
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Alexis -

CALCULATE(COUNT(Column), FILTER(Table, Condition || Condition || Condition || Condition))